# Python: Transparent Sprite againt background

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a game using pygame. I have loaded and `blit`ed the background onto my screen.
When I `blit` my sprite on top of the background, I get a white box around my sprite.

How do I get rid of the white box?
I have already tried using `.convert_alpha()` and `.convert()` and GIMP

Any ideas?
Thanks,

My code:

```
 background=pygame.image.load('space.jpg')
 spaceship=pygame.image.load('spaceship2.jpg')
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `png` because `jpg` can't has transparent pixels and `.convert_alpha()` doesn't work.

With `jpg` you can only try to set `color key` - the color in image which pygame will treat as transparent pixels.

see: [Surface.set_colorkey](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.set_colorkey)